# Unity game app, running while in sleep?

Tags: unity-game-engine

does a unity app still run while app is offline/sleep/exit, like the timer for Candy Crush.

or facebooks Cafe World's money system, inventory management refill of items while you are logged out/closes the app

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to set `Application.runInBackground`, however, that is only for Web and PC builds.

For example, in Android, your game runs as an Activity. Therefore, it will get paused when not in focus, that is done by the OS.

You could try **writing a Service that updates certain things for your game**. Then communicate your game to the Service once your game is unPaused. The Service will run even when the game is paused.

```
public void OnApplicationPause(bool paused) 
{
    if(paused) 
    {
    } 

    else 
    {
        // Grab information from the Service that ran the whole time.
    }
}
```

Information on how to build your own [**Service**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).